# ActiveMQ Webconsole not reading data-queue-data files

Tags: java, activemq-classic

We are using ActiveMQ 5.5.1 in our application.

The customer has reported that ActiveMQ is creating a lot of data-queue-data files and the total size is now nearing a GB. He wants to know what is causing this issue.

From our understanding of the ActiveMQ website, we understood that ActiveMQ is supposed to delete the data-queue-data files once they reach 32MB and all the messages in that file are processed.

Our activemq.xml uses <kahaPersistenceAdapter>, and this seems to generate data-queue-data files. We used the Webconsole of ActiveMQ to view the entries in the queue, but it did not list any. We tried replacing <kahaPersistenceAdapter> with <kahaDB>, and it generated a few .log files, and Webconsole is able to read those.

So how do we make Webconsole read the data-queue-data files?

Comment: Can you provide your full persistence store configuration from the activmq.xml?

Comment: @ErikWilliams, did you mean the persistence adapter? If yes, here it is:<persistenceAdapter><kahaPersistenceAdapter directory="${someDir}/activemq-data"/></persistenceAdapter>

Comment: Are you 100% (or 200%) sure that there are no unprocessed messages *anywhere* in your broker, neither in queues nor topics?  Because if there are, that's probably why your broker is holding onto data-queue-data files.  So make double-sure that there are absolutely no messages anywhere first...